# Iterate through Python Dictionary without knowing the specific keys

Tags: python

I can't seem to figure out how to write this piece of Python Code.

I need to read something in from a file, which is this:

```
Jake FJ49FJH
Bob FJ49GKH
```

I've imported the file into a dictionary. I then check if the number plate (following the names) contains the sequence of two letters, two numbers, then three letters. Here is that part of the code:

```
d = {} # Blank Dictionary

with open("plates.txt") as f:
  d = dict(x.rstrip().split(None, 1) for x in f) # Put file into dictionary

names = d.keys()
print(names)
#carReg = ??


a,b,c = carReg[:2],carReg[2:4],carReg[4:]
if all((a.isalpha(),b.isdigit(),c.isalpha(),len(c)== 3)):
    print("Valid Reg")
else:
    print("Invalid Reg")
    # Now get the name of the person with the invalid carReg
```

As you can see, I don't know what to put for `carReg`. I need to loop through the dictionary, like in a list when you can use an integer to get part of the list. If the program returns `Invalid Reg`, then I need to get the key that the invalid reg belongs to - which will be a name.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items); it'll give you the `(key, value)` pairs from the dictionary:

```
for name, car_registration in d.items():
```